# How can I implement the filter method to this code without deleting map method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to make my array of jokeComponents gets filtered to only display those that have fewer than X number of characters in the question.

How can I implement the filter method to this code without deleting map method?

```js
import React from "react"

import Joke from "./Joke"
import jokesData from "./jokesData"

function App() {
    const jokeComponents = jokesData.map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />)
    
    return (
        <div>
            {jokeComponents}            
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Why would you need to delete the map method? Put the filter before the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jokesData.filter(joke => joke.question.length > X).map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />)
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this? Whereby you filter your array of components by perform your predicated function against the question prop. And then render the filtered array (if that's the intended outcome)

```js
import React from "react"

import Joke from "./Joke"
import jokesData from "./jokesData"

function App() {
    const jokeComponents = jokesData.map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />);
    const filteredJokes = jokeComponents.filter((component) => component.props.question.length > 2);
    
    return (
        <div>
            {filteredJokes}            
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

This is initially filter out array with elements having question length less than value X.

```
import React from "react"

import Joke from "./Joke"
import jokesData from "./jokesData"

function App() {
    const jokeComponents = jokesData.filter(ele=>{ele.question.length>X}).map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />)
    
    return (
        <div>
            {jokeComponents}            
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react"

import Joke from "./Joke"
import jokesData from "./jokesData"

function App() {

  const filteredJokes = jokesData.filter(joke => joke.question.length > X);

   return filteredJokes.map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} {...joke}  />)
}

export default App
```